# How do I make Selenium update a Facebook profile picture

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, selenium-webdriver, dom-events

I am trying to make a Selenium webdriver (in control of Firefox) update the profile picture of a Facebook account it's logged into. 
I've used the typical suggestion that is to find the file input and send_keys my file's path, here's what I got:

```
image.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@title,'Choose a file to upload')]").send_keys(os.getcwd()+'test.png')
```

Anyways, here's the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/maste/PycharmProjects/accountGenerator/accountGenerator.py", line 136, in <module>
>       image.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@title,'Choose a file to upload')]").send_keys(os.getcwd()+'test.png')
>     File "C:\Users\maste\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
>       'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
>     File "C:\Users\maste\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>     File "C:\Users\maste\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\maste\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <<input id="js_h" class="_n _5f0v" type="file">> is not reachable by keyboard

That <> is `<input id="js_h" class="_n _5f0v" type="file">`, I can't find it anywhere in the HTML at all. Anyone got ideas?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API or if it is not possible to do it in the API don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Autoit and its editor for such file uploading actions what you have to do is just find the element button on which you have to upload file and on the action of the button you need to run autoit file what simply it will do is just run the click command from the button and select the file which you have described and upload it.

i have share link below so you can easily understand

https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/upload-file-using-autoit/

Answer (score 0):

The exception ElementNotInteractableException occurs when an element is found, but you can not perform any action on it. For example, you might click or call send keys, but the operation will eventually fail.

Such a situation could arise due to multiple reasons like these:

- The element is not visible / not fully displayed
- The element is off the screen
- The element hiding behind other elements or hidden itself
- It requires some action to perform by you to get it enabled
  it.

In such cases, you may try the following approaches:-

**1. Wait until the element gets visible or clickable**

```
WebDriverWait letsWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
letsWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(item)); 
letsWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(item));
```

**2. Scroll until the element comes under the display**

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(item);
```

**3. Use JavaScript to handle the DOM element**

```
JavascriptExecutor jScript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jScript.executeScript("var item = document.querySelector('locator'); item.value = 'your choice';")
```

However, you could also read this GitHub thread about this problem as several others are facing it as well in their respective scenarios: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5037

BTW, here is a post to explain on [handling file uploads using Selenium](https://www.techbeamers.com/handle-file-upload-selenium-webdriver/), you can check for a different approach or try Java instead of Python.